# Comparing signed data and signature in Android Market responses using Ruby on Rails

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rsa, google-play

I'm wondering does anyone have links to any literature on how to approach this problem.

I receive two sets of data from the Android Market; "Signed Data", a JSON representation of the purchase, and "Signature", a Base64 encoded, encrypted representation of the signed data.

I think the point is to use the public key to encrypt the signed data and compare it to the signature?

My strategy so far has been as follows:

1) Base64 decode the public key and use OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new to create a public key object

2) Base64 decode the signature returned from Android

3) Encrypt the signed data using the public key and compare with the signature

What is the correct way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:
[How do I verify Android In-app Billing with a server with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971031/how-do-i-verify-android-in-app-billing-with-a-server-with-ruby)

The Public Key object created in the first step has a handy `verify` method to compare the Base64 decoded data in step 2 with the signed data.

`verified = key.verify(OpenSSL::Digest::SHA1.new, Base64.decode64(signature), signed_data)`

Happiness.