# In-app billing, how to update server side database

Tags: php, android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement a feature to update my server side database when someone purchases a managed item in my Android application.

Basically I want the user to be able to log on to my website when the managed item have been purchased but not before.
Can someone please provide me with details on how to accomplish this.
Someone I would like to send a username/email or similar to the web page that I can use to update the server database. However I need to make sure this cannot be sent by a user that have not purchased the managed item in my Android application

I have read some good post on this subject, but I still don't see how I can apply this in my solution

- [How do I verify Android In-app Billing with a server with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971031/how-do-i-verify-android-in-app-billing-with-a-server-with-ruby)
- http://crazyviraj.blogspot.se/2011/06/some-notes-on-implementing-in-app.html

Best regards

Comment: Your first bullet pretty much outlines the steps to take.  Maybe you can add some detail to your question to explain exactly how far you got and where you are stuck.

Comment: The thing that I'm missing is how do I send a username from the application to my server. And to prevent it from being possible to resend another username to the server (e.g. if app is uninstalled/installed), thus enabling another account as well.

I have basically copied the sample code for billing from the Android SDK and I have a working solution to buy managed item without interacting with my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google play store sends signed data and signature of each individual purchase. On successful purchase of an item from your android application, the application needs to send in the signed data and signature to your server. This data then needs to be verified against the public key. On successful verification, you can then intimate the android application with the success response and the required credentials for him to login.

**EDIT :**
[Android Inapp Billing Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html)
[Sample Inapp Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download)
[Sample BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-broadcast-receiver)

Please check the android sample inapp billing implementation. That has a dungeon's example which implements inapp billing. You need to implement a BroadcastReceiver which gets the data back from GooglePlay. com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED intent represents that a purchase has happened. Now you can get the signed data and signature from the intent like

```
String signedData = intent.getStringExtra("inapp_signed_data");
String signature = intent.getStringExtra("inapp_signature");
```

Now you may need to pass in this data to your server to identify the user who actually purchased it. Hope it helps.

Comment: thx for the response, this is pretty much how I have understood it as well. But where do I send e.g. username/email from the app to my server? Is this part of the data or how should this be sent?
If you can give some example using the official billing code that would be really helpful

Comment: Thx for the update. I have everything working using the Google sample code already, but without any server side interaction.
I still don't see how I can know what username/email etc that the user have (for me to know what user to update on the server database)
Can I decide what is part of the signedData, e.g. is this where I should include an username/email?

Comment: Approach 1: Your android app should have login, where you get the username/email and password, validate the credentials against your server. If it is so then things are simple, you just need to make a call to the server with this signed data, signature whatever google play sends you and also the username/email who is logged in. This request from Android should be a post request over https preferably so that you can persist the username, signed data and signature.

Comment: Approach 2: You dont have a login, you can just save the signed data and signature alone in the server and you can just keep track of the purchase requests made for the same signeddata and signature.

Comment: I would prefer going with the first approach with using the device's primary email id as your login in android app, and dunno allow more than two or three different devices to download the content from your server for the same signed data and signature. Hope it helps.